# Unable to add .env files to gitignore?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've added a several entries as below to my `.gitignore`

```
.env
.env.production
.env.staging
.env.uat
```

Now what I'm confused is it doesn't seem to be taking effect, both visually on VS Code nor when I run `git status`, it doesn't list all the files that I'm expecting to be removed/deleted? I must've missed something obvious but I couldn't spot it

[image]

Visual on VS Code as below:

[image]

Comment: Show the corresponding `git status` you're having problems with. `.gitignore` does not remove anything, it just removes them as long as they are unstaged/untracked from `git status`.

Comment: @Zaya yes I've tried `*.env` as well as `.env*`

Comment: @zerkms: Do have a look on updated question

Comment: your screenshot looks okay, what's your problem again?

Comment: @zerkms: From VS Code, I'm expecting if the entry added to `.gitignore`, VSCode will show a light grey on the file as shown above screenshot. At the same time, unstaged changes I'm expecting several of these file being listed as deleted right?

Comment: Or actually i understood wrongly?

Comment: "several of these file being listed as deleted right?" --- nope, `.gitignore` does not delete anything, it just would ignore them from `git status` if you have not tracked/staged them before. As long as a file is tracked - `.gitignore` does not affect it in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From VS Code, I'm expecting if the entry added to `.gitignore`, VSCode will show a light grey on the file as shown above screenshot.

No: you need to remove them from Git first:

```
git rm --cached -- .env;      
git rm --cached -- .env.*
```

Then the .gitignore would take effect, and VSCode would reflect the new state of those files.

Comment: Indeed after running the code it's reflecting correctly. I was confused coz I tried on other files was reflecting immediately, but not this 4 files

Comment: @Isaac if those "other files" were not tet added to Git index, then VSCode would reflect their new ignored states immediately.